# SetState overwrites previous state even with spread operator React.JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm facing an issue with `setState` inside my `handleChange`.
So here in code after clicking `addList` a `div` with `input` and `button` will appear, then when i type inside `input` the `input state` will update and after clicking Add button the `div` will disappear.
so my problem is next time when clicking `addList` the value of previous input is still there and the `hideAddList handler` does not set the `input` state to empty and also when I type in the new opened `div` the previous `input state` will overwrite. even with indexing and spread operator its still same problem.

what should I do?

```js
export class myClass extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            input: [{ title: '' }]

        };
        this.addList = this.addList.bind(this);
        this.hideAddList = this.hideAddList.bind(this);
        this.titleHandleChange = this.titleHandleChange.bind(this);
        

    }
    
    addList() {
       var x = document.getElementById("btn-list")
       var y = document.getElementById("add-button")
       x.style.display = 'none'
       y.style.display = ''
    }

    hideAddList() {
        var x = document.getElementById("btn-list")
        var y = document.getElementById("add-button")
        x.style.display = ''
        y.style.display = 'none';
        this.setState(prevState => ({ input: [...prevState.input, {title:''}]}))  
    }
     HandleChange(e, index){
       const { name, value } = e.target;
       const list = [...this.state.input];
       list[index][name] = value;
       this.setState({ input: list});
    }
    
   render() {
        return (
          <div>
          <button id="btn-list" className="btn btn-default btn-list" type="submit" onClick={this.addList}>Add Another List</button>
                        {this.state.input.map((x, i) => {
                                return (
                                    <div key={i} id="add-button" className="add-button" style={{ display: "none" }}>
                                        <input id="input" type="text" onChange={(e) => {this.HandleChange(e, i)}} value={x.title} name="title" className="form-control add-input" />
                                        <button className="btn btn-default btn-list-add" onClick={this.hideAddList} type="submit">Add</button>
                                    </div>
                                    )})}
          </div>
        )
     }
        
}

export default myClass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the code you provided, you will always get the first "add-button" element each time you call `addList`, because all of your list items have the same id.

```
{this.state.input.map((x, i) => {
...
 <div key={i} id="add-button" ...> // here! they got the same id!
```

so what happened here is that you are actually editing the first item all the time. you will need to add different id to your elements. and the `AddList` should get the last item index.

for example:

```
AddList()
...
{this.state.input.map((x, i) => {
            return (
               <div key={i} id={`add-button-${i}`} .... // here! add unique id for each item!
```

the whole code should be like this:

```js
export default class myClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: [{title: ''}],
    };
    this.addList = this.addList.bind(this);
    this.hideAddList = this.hideAddList.bind(this);
    this.titleHandleChange = this.titleHandleChange.bind(this);
  }

  addList() {
    var lastItemIndex = this.state.input.length - 1; // you need to get the last item's index to make sure that you display the latest item
    var x = document.getElementById('btn-list');
    var y = document.getElementById(`add-button-${lastItemIndex}`);
    x.style.display = 'none';
    y.style.display = '';
  }

  hideAddList(i) {
    var x = document.getElementById('btn-list');
    var y = document.getElementById(`add-button-${i}`);
    x.style.display = '';
    y.style.display = 'none';
    this.setState(prevState => ({input: [...prevState.input, {title: ''}]}));
  }
  titleHandleChange(e, index) {
    const {name, value} = e.target;
    const list = [...this.state.input];
    list[index][name] = value;
    this.setState({input: list});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          id="btn-list"
          className="btn btn-default btn-list"
          type="submit"
          onClick={this.addList}>
          Add Another List
        </button>
        {this.state.input.map((x, i) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={i}
              id={`add-button-${i}`}
              className="add-button"
              style={{display: 'none'}}>
              <input
                id="input"
                type="text"
                onChange={e => {
                  this.titleHandleChange(e, i);
                }}
                value={x.title}
                name="title"
                className="form-control add-input"
              />
              <button
                className="btn btn-default btn-list-add"
                onClick={() => this.hideAddList(i)}
                type="submit">
                Add
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

for debugging, maybe you can try to log index out in `titleHandleChange`, so you can find out which item that you're actually editing.

ps, you could write `export default class MyClass extends ...` so you don't need to write `export default MyClass` at the end of the file again.

Comment: Thanks for helping and your complete guide :)

Answer (score 0):

The state has already been changed correctly. You can add a console log to see it:

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
    ...
```

The reason that it is not showing on your screen is the `{display: 'none'}` that you set for id 'add-button'. Your `var y = document.getElementById("add-button")`  will just get the first element, but not the whole list of elements.

FYI it is not quite right to use `document.getElementById` in a react project for your case. It should be done by state. Here is a complete example:

```
export class MyClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: [{title: ''}],
      showAnotherListBtn: true,
      showList: false,
    };
  }

  onClickAnotherListBtn = () => {
    this.setState({
      showAnotherListBtn: false,
      showList: true,
    });
  }

  addList = () => {
    this.setState({
      input: [...this.state.input, {title: ''}],
    });
  }

  handleChange(e, index) {
    const {name, value} = e.target;
    const list = [...this.state.input];
    list[index][name] = value;
    this.setState({input: list});
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.showAnotherListBtn ?
          <button id="btn-list" className="btn btn-default btn-list" type="submit" onClick={this.onClickAnotherListBtn}>Add Another
            List</button> : null}
        {this.state.showList && this.state.input.map((x, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i} id="add-button" className="add-button">
              <input id="input" type="text" onChange={(e) => {
                this.handleChange(e, i)
              }} value={x.title} name="title" className="form-control add-input"/>
              <button className="btn btn-default btn-list-add" onClick={this.addList} type="submit">Add</button>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MyClass
```

As you can see from the above code, you an just use a boolean state to determine whether you should show the element or not.

Hope this helps ;)